Rails.application.reloader.to_prepare and "include" in initializer
I have this kinda large initializer:
  # File: app/config/initializers/money.rb

  Money.locale_backend = :i18n

  MoneyRails.configure do |config|

     include OpenExchangeRatesBankConfig
     include GoogleCurrencyExchangeBankConfig

     lots of lines here

And I'm getting the warning message:
 DEPRECATION WARNING: Initialization autoloaded the constants
 OpenExchangeRatesBankConfig and GoogleCurrencyExchangeBankConfig.

 Being able to do this is deprecated. Autoloading during initialization is going
 to be an error condition in future versions of Rails.

It suggests to use the call back "Rails.application.reloader.to_prepare", but I don't have idea how to use it in the initializer. If I try to wrap the whole initializer in the callback, I'm getting:
NoMethodError:   undefined method `include'

Refering to the line "include OpenExchangeRatesBankConfig". I read the Rails Guide regarding Zeitwerk, but even so, I'm not sure how to fix the issue.

Add require statements at the top, like ‘require 'money/bank/openexchangerates_bank'’ — then wrap everything else in the prepare statement

You may wrap your whole initializer into : Rails.application.config.after_initialize do end
